# related field from inherited model in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

i have a model that inherits **res.partner** model

```
class supplierDetails(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

   farmer_code = fields.Char(string="Farmer's Code")
```

Now i want the values from farmer_code in another model, so as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40104725) answer, i reached this far.

```
class productTest(models.Model):
     _name = 'quality.physical'
     _inherit = 'res.partner'

frm_code_ids = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string="Farmer Code")
    frm_cod = fields.Char(related='frm_code_ids.farmer_code',store=True,readonly=True)
```

Now i am getting **KeyError: 'farmer_code'**. What do i do to fix this?         Thanks in advance.

Comment: For making related field you must have 'farmer_code' field in res.partner model.

Comment: @AvaniSomaiya , Sorry, copied different field to the question. I've corrected the question.

Comment: You have to remove '_inherit =  res.partner ' line form your productTest class.

Comment: @AvaniSomaiya, still same error

Comment: First, comment on the code of productTest class, restart the service and upgrade your module. After successfully upgrade module uncomment the code of productTest class. And again restart the service & upgrade module.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, repeat the process step by step make sure the `res.partner` have this field you may forget to put the class in the `__init__.py` file.

```py
     # related field without store is like a compute field it's computed on fly
     related_field_name = fields.FieldType(related='your_m2o.target_field_name')
```

If you put `store=True` it will be added to the database and recomputed whenever you change the value of `many2one`.

You can go more than one level ex: `your_m2m.another_m2o_field.target_field_name`.

Field type should be the same as the target field.

Just make sure the target model have that field.

Comment: The first model (supplierDetails class)happens to be in another module. Could that be the problem?

Comment: did you put the dependency on that module (addon) in `__manisfest__`, and are you sure the error is in this line? you didn't use this field in another place?